# ADK: How-To create a streaming IP Camera Application with android Camera API

Tags: android, api, video, stream, camera

I want to make an android applications, which streams video from the android back camera using the internet connection.

For example: On the android phone on port 80 a webserver is running which shows the actual pic (and maybe refresh every half second or better more).

... or... using another streaming protocol (i.e. RTP) and consuming it from a client.

Can someone give me some hints how to access the camera and stream it? The stream should be embedded in a website.

I know this this is a larger project and there are already apps, but i want to do this as education project.

Can someone give me some hints?

Comment: did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe here (http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartcam) is the project that does all you asked about (except that there is a camera device on PC rather than web server, as you requested). It is opensource, so you can pick ideas for your education project.

Good luck!